# You may need an appropriate loader - React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, expo

Im trying to use a ui library in my react native project - i am using the expo cli for it.
Im trying to use native-base however when i add it to the project i am told that i need to add a webpack loader.

Here is my code:

```
// first i ran expo install native-base
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Badge, Text, Icon } from 'native-base';
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

and this is the error message im getting

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders        
| } from 'react-native'
| import { isIphoneX } from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper'
> import type { KeyboardAwareInterface } from './KeyboardAwareInterface'
| 
| const _KAM_DEFAULT_TAB_BAR_HEIGHT: number = isIphoneX() ? 83 : 49
```

Has anyone dealt with this? Do i have to export from expo to use a UI library?

Comment: looks like you are trying to import a typescript folder into a javascript project. that is why you are getting this error. look into using the library with just javascript

Comment: also, check [this](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3231) out, it has the same problem as yours

Comment: To add to what @akram-adel is saying, you can also try to use `typescript` with your project. Some examples are given in the `create-react-app` documentation on how to handle this. You can [try to add `typescript`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) or start fresh and [have `create-react-app` handle that for you](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#creating-a-typescript-app)

Comment: Hey. Recently native-base has some bugs and they are not going to fix them soon as the owners said in issues.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@red-elephant/native-base
This is a package you can use temporarily till the new updates from the native-base.

Comment: That does seem to be the case but i cant find any solution for it